# BPMN one gate for paths & event

Tags: mapping, modeling, bpmn, business-process-management

Is it possible and correct to use same XOR gateway for outcoming paths and event?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, it would be syntactically incorrect.

The XOR gateway is called “data-based exclusive gateway” in the BPMN standard. The selection of the outgoing flow is simply done by finding a match within the data that the incoming flow has provided. The event that you are waiting for is, however, not treated as data.

You could use an **event**-based exclusive gateway instead. It could have two outgoing flows: one pointing towards a “message received” event and another one with the “14 days have passed” event. After the “message received” event, you could then plug in the XOR gateway with its two “yes” and “no” flows as in your picture.

Alternatively, you could remove the flow towards the timer event from the XOR gateway in your picture and attach it as an interrupting boundary timer event to the task immediately preceding the XOR gateway.

Answer (score 0):

### In short

The BPMN exclusive gate is not a flowchart decision node: the exclusive gate is not a decision-making task that would start with its incoming flow.  The gate is where the decision is IMMEDIATELY made based on the data available at that moment of the incoming flow. So it's never the gate that will cause delays.

### Some more details

The [exclusive gate](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/modeler/bpmn/exclusive-gateways/) can have multiple outgoing flows, but exactly one must be chosen:

- each flow must be associated with a condition expression based on the the state of play (data available) when reaching the gate;
- one flow can be a default that is chose if none to the other conditions are true. (Normally you'd mark the default flow with a `/` across the line.)

This is not what you want here: the flow to the timer cannot be a default that would be chosen **instead of** the accepted complaint. The timer flow seems to be an **alternate path** that replaces the way through the gate.  I understand that it's  a timeout for something  preceding the gate.

The right solution will then depend on what makes the timer start to tick:

- If it is the task immediately preceding the gate, then just add an [interrupting timer boundary event](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/modeler/bpmn/timer-events/) of that task:
  [image]
- If it is the reception of some message further ahead, then it might be slightly more difficult, considering that some elements might have to be grouped in an [embedded subprocess](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/modeler/bpmn/embedded-subprocesses/) to be able to interrupt the right sequence.